# Unable to read a text file

Tags: python, text, ioerror

Newbie here and I'm trying to do something that I think should be fairly simple but I am having a really hard time accomplishing. I just want to print whatever it is that I wrote to a file. When trying to read the file I get error: IOError: File not open for reading. If I am understanding this correctly, the file should still be open when I assign it to 'a' since it is under the 'with' statement. 'a' is just a variable containing a string at this point and I should be able to print it off whenever.

```
with open("sample.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("Hello world!")
    a = file.read()

print(a)
```

Comment: The error says it all - the file isn't opened for reading. You opened the file in (text) write mode, `w`, but you need to open it in `r+` or `w+` mode

Comment: You mention "w" for writable. change it for "r"  and use the code again for open and read.

Answer (score 3):

There are two *errors* on your code:

1. As @Astro Orbis said, you are using the wrong file mode. You should use `r+` if you want to write at the end of the file and read it, or `w+` if you also want to reply to the current document data.
2. After doing the `write`, your file pointer is going to be at the end of the file, so the `read` method is not going to read anything because is nothing left to read. You should do a `file.seek(0)` after the write in order to put the pointer at the beginning of the file.

```python
with open("sample.txt", "r+") as file:
    file.write("Hello world!")
    file.seek(0)
    a = file.read()
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong file mode.
The one you're using right now, (w), lets you exclusively write to the file.
Here's a good source for file modes:  https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/python/python-file-modes-open-write-append-r-r-w-w-x-etc/